# .htaccess file convert to nginx

Tags: .htaccess, nginx

I have below .htaccess file and need to covert to nginx.Im having trouble with converting this. Im not nginx expert.

```
RewriteEngine On
   
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options -Indexes

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . index.php [L,QSA]
# Performace optimization  
# BEGIN Compress text files
<ifModule mod_deflate.c>
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/xml text/css text/plain
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/svg+xml application/xhtml+xml application/xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rdf+xml application/rss+xml application/atom+xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/javascript application/javascript application/x-javascript application/json
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-ttf application/x-font-otf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/truetype font/opentype
</ifModule>
# END Compress text files

# BEGIN Expire headers
<ifModule mod_expires.c>
  ExpiresActive On
  ExpiresDefault "access plus 5 seconds"
  ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 31536000 seconds"
  ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 31536000 seconds"
  ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 31536000 seconds"
  ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 31536000 seconds"
  ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access plus 31536000 seconds"
  ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 31536000 seconds"
  ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 31536000 seconds"
  ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 31536000 seconds"
  ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access plus 31536000 seconds"
</ifModule>
# END Expire headers
# BEGIN Cache-Control Headers
<ifModule mod_headers.c>
  <filesMatch ".(ico|jpe?g|png|gif|swf)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "public"
  </filesMatch>
  <filesMatch ".(css)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "public"
  </filesMatch>
  <filesMatch ".(js)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "private"
  </filesMatch>
  <filesMatch ".(x?html?|php)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "private, must-revalidate"
  </filesMatch>

  <filesMatch ".(woff|woff2|ttf|otf|eot)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=31536000 private, must-revalidate"
  </filesMatch>
</ifModule>
```

i tried a few online .htaccess converter but it didn't work can some one please let me know how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adjust the `server` block according to your hostname, protocol etc.

```
map $sent_http_content_type $expires {
    image/x-icon                   31536000;
    image/jpeg                     31536000;
    image/png                      31536000;
    image/gif                      31536000;
    application/x-shockwave-flash  31536000;
    text/css                       31536000;
    text/javascript                31536000;
    application/javascript         31536000;
    application/x-javascript       31536000;
    default                        5;
}

map $request_filename $cache_control {
    ~\.(ico|jpe?g|png|gif|swf)$    "public";
    ~\.css$                        "public";
    ~\.js$                         "private";
    ~\.(x?html?|php)$              "private, must-revalidate";
    ~\.(woff|woff2|ttf|otf|eot)$   "max-age=31536000 private, must-revalidate";
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;
    root /your/root/path;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;
    gzip on;
    gzip_types text/html text/xml text/css text/plain
               image/svg+xml application/xhtml+xml application/xml
               application/rdf+xml application/rss+xml application/atom+xml
               text/javascript application/javascript application/x-javascript application/json
               application/x-font-ttf application/x-font-otf
               font/truetype font/opentype;
    expires $expires;
    add_header Cache-Control $cache_control;
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    }
    location ~ \.php$ {
        # your PHP handler here
    }
}
```